# Git pushes to master

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow

I'm working in branch `feature/something`. When I do `git status`, it says:

```
On branch feature/something
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature/something'.
```

But when I've just done `git push`, it pushed all my changes in both `origin/feature/something` and `master`.

Why could it happen? I thought by default `git push` pushes to the remote branch with the same name. Am I wrong?

I've just installed git-flow, maybe that's default behavior for it?

Comment: Actually, it pushes all local branches that are tracking your remote. You can specify it though, something like `git push origin feature/something` so it will only push that branch.

Comment: I also have `develop` branch, but it wasn't pushed. I push from that branch usually, and it works fine, and pushes only to `original/develop`.

Comment: does your local `develop` branch track the one on `origin` as an upstream? if memory serves, you can still tell git to push it if it doesn't track origin's version automatically, at least if you run something like `git push origin develop`. What's the output of `git status` when you're in `develop`? it should show you the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configurable variable `push.default` controls what is pushed if you do not specify what to push:<sup>1</sup>

```
$ git config --get push.default
nothing
```

(for example—this is a setting I might use at times).  For the examples below, let's assume that you have branches `a`, `b`, and `c` and your remote is named `origin`.  Furthermore, let's say branch `a` is associated with `origin/a`—i.e., you'll see messages like `"Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/a'."`—while `b` is associated with `origin/longb` and `c` has no upstream (yet).

There are five possible values:

- `nothing`: Produce an error, and push nothing.
- `current`: Push the current branch, to a branch of the same name.  If you are on `a`, this will push to `origin/a`.  If you're on branch `b` or `c` this will *create* a branch of the same name on `origin`.
- `upstream`: push the current branch to its corresponding upstream name.  If you are on `a`, this will push to `origin/a`.  If you are on `b`, you'll push to `origin/longb`.  If you're on `c` you'll get an error: `The current branch c has no upstream branch.`
- `simple`: Similar to `upstream` but fail if the upstream branch name does not match the local branch name.  If you're on `a`, this pushes to `a`; if you're on either `b` or `c` you will get an error.
- `matching`: Push all branches that have the same names.  Since `b` and `longb` are different and `c` does not yet exist on the remote, no matter which branch you are on, you will just push `a`.

If you have not set `push.default` at all, the default `push.default` setting in git 2.0 is `simple`, but in older versions, it is `matching`.  You probably have an older version of git, and are using the defaults (although your comment above suggests something more complex).

See [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for (much) more.

---

<sup>1</sup>To specify what to push, either do it explicitly:

```
git push origin X:upstream_name_for_X
```

or:

```
git push origin Y   # this "means" Y:Y
```

or you can set `remote.origin.push` to a set of refspecs (you can set more than one value).  You can also set `branch.name.pushremote` for particularly esoteric setups, where a branch has one upstream for pulling (fetching and merge-or-rebase) but a different place for pushing.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. Now I definitely know more about how git works.